# adding audio to mosaic video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I made a mosaic from 4 different videos.
And it looks somewhat fine not the best quality, what do I edit in the command for a better quality of video ?

And how do I take the audio from all of the videos, and mix it into the final mosaic video ( just in one channel )
Below is the command I used

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -i 2.mkv -i 3.mkv -i 4.mkv -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=640x480 [base]; [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperright]; [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerleft]; [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerright]; [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1]; [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2]; [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [tmp3]; [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=240" -c:v libx264 outpu2t.mkv
```

Comment: I will try adding "-preset veryslow -crf 0" to the command for higher quality of video

Comment: "not the best quality" use `-crf 18` or so. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264). Mix audio: use amix or amerge filter, see [Vertically or horizontally stack several videos using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/1109017).

Answer (score 0):

When working with x264, there are three parameters that contribute the most to the output quality:

- -level:v is about the output file level - try `3.1` for best compatibility and `4.0` (or higher) for good quality
- -profile:v is about the profile in the given level - try `baseline` for best compatibility and `high` for good quality
- -b:v is about the bandwidth of the video. For a 640x480 video as you want it, try `2500K`

You might also want to reconsider your output size of 640x480 - this is basic SD quality.

Comment: ah thanks! where can I read about stuff like this ?

Comment: In the ffmpeg documentation ;-)

Comment: of course! 
embarrassing hehe :))